# Conditional HTML rendering in SvelteKit not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, json, svelte

So I have a footer component that reads links from a JSON file. I have a particular header that I only want to have present if the corresponding JSON property is not blank (i.e., if there's no link provided, it won't show up.) My current setup looks a little like this:

```html
{#if (socialMediaLinks["contactUs"] !== "")}
  <a href={socialMediaLinks["contactUs"]}>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  </a>
{/if}
```

Issue being, this code results in the h2 *always* being visible, even with no link provided. If i try and alter the if to

```
{#if (socialMediaLinks["contactUs"] === "")}
```

the link doesn't show even if the property isn't blank.

This behavior feels backwards. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just check then length of the string and if it's longer than a string with only the markup, the condition is true.
And the "@html" let the svelte compiler know, that the content ist already HTML.

```
if (socialMediaLinks["contactUs"].length > 9){
    {@html socialMediaLinks["contactUs"]}
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your IF, I'm guessing.  The value of `socialMediaLinks["contactUs"]` might be either `null` or `undefined` and you are requesting exact comparison (triple operator).

This should work:

```html
{#if (socialMediaLinks["contactUs"])}
  <a href={socialMediaLinks["contactUs"]}>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  </a>
{/if}
```